# How to do forms Material Style

Tags: android, material-design

How do you achieve the "Material look" with the different form controls on Android?

I've seen examples with floating label and edittext, but there is little information about how to create Spinners, RadioButtons, section dividers, etc. and in general any kind of form with a Material look.

Comment: see the official doc:https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Make you activity a descendant of `AppCompatActivity`. Then all the widgets you use will be automatically substituted to their `AppCompat` implementation.

For `AppCompatActivity` you should add in `build.gradle` file of the project:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
```

Currently, the latest supportLibVersion is 25.2.0. Thus,

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you got dislikes, because it is a very general question. 
I'll help you and like your post,

as for your question
again it's very very general questino
you can do for example for text views to have more "Material Design" look, you can wrap them in a style like this one:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

as for the rest you just have to google how to style each element to fit your specific layout and the google material design guidlines